# UITableView weird reloadData issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am stuck in a really weird issue, What em doing is calling `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest` in which i reload tableView and it does it without any issue. This scenario works fine while em standing on the same ViewController while request response is received. The issue arises when I call `sendAsynchronousRequest` and move from that ViewController and then come back to it before the request gives the response. This time the TableView `reloadData` gets called but doesn't do anything on the View. I call the reloadData in this `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` for it to run on `mainThread`.

Any help in this regard would be great.

**Edit 1:**

Here's what i have gotten far till now.. when i start the NSURLConnection asyncRequest it keeps the reference to the tableView and array that it has at that current time.. But when i navigate off from that view and then come back the view is reinitialized so the tableView and array has new references. So when the asyncRequest calls tableView ReloadData, it calls reload for the older referenced tableView rather than the one that is now visible hence not reloading the tableView… hope now you can help.

Comment: did u put breakpoints and checked whether there is a poper call to dispatch_asyn and cellforrows?

Comment: Looks like you reloading one tableview and displaying another.

Comment: It calls `numberOfRowsInSection` but doesn't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`..

Comment: There's only a single UITableView in my ViewController

Comment: When it calls `numberOfRowsInSection` is the number correct?  Also, is `reloadData` called on the async thread or the main thread?

Comment: yes the count is correct int `numberOfRowsInSection`… It's called on mainThread within `NSURLConnection asyncRequest`..

Comment: Have you checked the data used for representing the table view? NSLog it and see the value.

Comment: @Danyun yes and its correct...

Answer (score 2):

Rather than reloading tableview on main thread, try to reload it once you get data and the data is parsed. Switching between views may cause your tableview to reload before the data comes from server resulting blank tableview and this is caused due to calling some methods on main thread.

EDIT: Try to initialize tableview in viewdidload only and array just after you get response from server and before loading data in it.

Comment: actually em uploading data in the asyncRequest not downloading data… I have to reload the tableView once the data is uploaded…

Comment: OK so you can reload tableview after data is uploaded ie. success response comes from server.

Comment: yes thats what em doing.. after success or failure of request, I reload tableView which works fine while standing on the same view but gives issue when i change the view controller and come back to that view

Comment: It may occur if you initialize the array in viewwillappear

Comment: so what would be the solution to this..? I have to display the contents of the cell using that initialization

Comment: The solution will be that just initialize the array after you get data from the server or success response from the server.